# Visual Basic 438 Error When Assigning String to Cell

Tags: excel, vba

I copied this text from the "Introduction to Excel VBA Programming" textbook by Guojun Guo:

```
Sub AccessObject()
Application.ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(1).Cells(1,2).Value = "A String"
End Sub
```

I get a 438 Error. When I get rid of the Application.ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(1) prefix the code runs. I do not know why this prefix gives the 438 Error. Is this just deprecated or are my settings wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: Did you put that code into the `ThisWorkook` code module and run it while having several Excel files open at once?

Comment: I had a Chart open and I didn't realize it. Probably should have used a new workbook, but I appreciate the insight.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**edit:** *see additional material at the end in response to [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74924509/visual-basic-438-error-when-assigning-string-to-cell/74924706#comment132221372_74924706)*

It's possible to have sheets in a workbook which aren't worksheets and thus don't have cells. Chart sheets are an example of this. You can check which type of sheet that `Sheets(1)` is by adding this to your code:

```
MsgBox Application.ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(1).Type
```

If the value displayed in the message box is -4167, then Sheets(1) is a worksheet. For anything else, consult the values for [xlSheetType](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/office/vba/api/excel.xlsheettype)

But the simpler solution is to change to using `Worksheets(1)` instead, because that will only look at worksheets. You can also remove `Application.ActiveWorkbook` *(**edit:** but see below)* because that is the default, which leaves you with:

```
Worksheets(1).Cells(1, 2).Value = "A String"
```

---

**edit:** As pointed out in [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74924509/visual-basic-438-error-when-assigning-string-to-cell/74924706#comment132221372_74924706), `Application.ActiveWorkbook` is not the default when the code in question is in a `ThisWorkbook` module. So, either specify `ActiveWorkbook` if you want your macro to affect whichever workbook is currently active (there shouldn't be any need to specify Application though):

```
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Cells(1, 2).Value = "A String"
```

Or, if you want your macro to affect the same workbook that the macro code is in, either specify `ThisWorkbook` in a normal module:

```
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Cells(1, 2).Value = "A String"
```

Or put the code in the `ThisWorkbook` module and don't specify anything about the workbook:

```
Worksheets(1).Cells(1, 2).Value = "A String"
```

Or, if you want the code to affect a specific workbook that isn't the one which contains the macro and isn't necessarily the active workbook, then capture a reference to that other workbook in a variable and refer to that. A common way to do this is when you open that other workbook:

```
Dim wb As Workbook
Set wb = Workbooks.Open("filename goes here")

' do stuff

wb.Sheets(1).Cells(1, 2).Value = "A String"

' do other stuff - including potentially saving the workbook

wb.Close
Set wb = Nothing
```

Comment: `You can also remove Application.ActiveWorkbook because that is the default` - no, it isn't. Or rather, it may change the behaviour here. If the code resides in the `ThisWorkbooks` code module, `Sheets` will refer to the sheets of that workbook, not of the active workbook. If the code resides anywhere else, `Sheets` will resolve to `Application.Sheets`. Adding `Application.ActiveWorkbook.` eliminates that ambiguity.

Comment: @GSerg thanks for the correction! I've incorporated that detail into the answer and added some other cases